# Modifying Object in Multi-threaded Application

Tags: c++, multithreading

First thread

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <thread>

void changeDir(int&dir)
{
    switch (getch()) {
    case 'a':
        dir = 1;
        break;
    case 'd':
        dir = 2;
        break;
    case 'w':
        dir = 3;
        break;
    case 's':
        dir = 4;
        break;
    }
}
```

Second thread

```c
void coreGame(int&dir,int&x,int&y)
{
    switch (dir) {
    case 1:
        x--;
        break;
    case 2:
        x++;
        break;
    case 3:
        y--;
        break;
    case 4:
        y++;
        break;
    }
}
```

Main function that starts the threads

```c
game()
{
    int x = 13;
    int y = 23;
    int dir = 0;

    std::thread movement(changeDir, dir);
    std::thread theRest(coreGame, dir,x,y);

    while (true) {
        if (movement.joinable()) {
            movement.join();
        }
        if (theRest.joinable()) {
            theRest.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Why does qtcreator give me errors on this. The compiler refuse to show me what line is incorrect, instead, it just gives me  errors when I try to compile.

I have tried defining the functions on top this which does nothing. I have also tried creating the threads in `main()` but this only creates more problems.

Comment: Maybe include the errors that you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I believe what you are trying to achieve might not be possible given that there is a potential race hazard, that is, the memory location of dir, x, y are not independent nor atomic. So your program might not run as expected. A potential fix is to make it a global variable (which also had the problem with Thread-Local Storage/TLS) and then set a semaphore to control the order of access, or just make it sequential but asynchronous in nature (so revert this faulty discrete system back to a continuous flow).

Comment: thx for the response, it kind sucks but i guess I have no choice

Answer (score 0):

Found it out. had to use. std::ref()
example:

```
std::thread movement(changeDir, std::ref(dir));
```

Comment: nvm, now it just does nothing